# Error creating WebGL context enyo

Tags: three.js, webgl, enyo

I am trying simple spinning cube sample of `three.js` in `enyo` framework.
I am getting error as 
`THREE.WebGLRenderer:Error creating WebGL context`.

Here is my code:

```
enyo.kind({
name:"Cubetest",
create:function () {
    // body...
    this.inherited(arguments);
            this.drawCube();
            //alert("in create");
},
rendered : function(){
    this.inherited(arguments);

    //this.drawCube();
},
drawCube : function(){
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    console.log(scene);
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    console.log(camera);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );

    console.log(cube);
    console.log(scene);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    var render = function () {

        requestAnimationFrame( render );

        cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    render();

}
});
```

What may be problem here?
It supports `CanvasRenderer`.
If I replace `WebGLRenderer` by `CanvasRenderer`,it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are running into is that you are appending a DOM node to the body before Enyo has created its DOM nodes. When Enyo creates its nodes, it wipes out the one created by three. You should leave DOM manipulation to Enyo, for the most part.

In Enyo, you do not have a DOM node until after `rendered()` is called. You should only create the three DOM node within the node created for your kind. You can get the DOM node from Enyo by calling `this.hasNode()`, which will return the DOM node (or `null` if `rendered()` has not been called yet).

Change your method to have three use your kind's node and things should work better.

Comment: I think I can also use method `rendered` ?

Comment: I meant to use `rendered()`.

Comment: You'll need to update your sample code. I'm fairly sure the problem has to do with supplying the DOM node for three to render into. It could also have something to do with supplying the correct dimensions for the node. I suggest adding a fiddle.